# Close responsive menu on clicking a <li>

Tags: javascript, html

i just tried to do a JS which is closing my menu when i press a "

" button but it doesn't work, there is my html code.

```
<input class="contact-btn" type="button" value="Contacteaza-ma"/>
    <button id="but-menu" class="menu-btn" onclick="openMenu()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars menu-btn__icon"></i>
    </button>
    <div id="mobile-nav" class="mobile-navigation">
        <buttton onclick="closeMenu()" class="close-btn"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></buttton>
        <div class="logo">
            <img class="logo__image" src="images/home-image.png"/>
            <p class="logo__text">Cristi Popescu</p>
        </div>
        <nav class="mobile-navigation__navigation">
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;" class="mobile-navigation__navigation-list">
                <li><a class="mobile-navigation__navigation-link" href="#about">DESPRE
                    MINE</a></li>
                <li><a class="mobile-navigation__navigation-link" href="#exp">EXPERIENTA</a></li>
                <li><a class="mobile-navigation__navigation-link" href="#edu">EDUCATIE</a></li>
                <li><a class="mobile-navigation__navigation-link" href="#apt">APTITUDINI</a></li>
                <li><a class="mobile-navigation__navigation-link" href="#ctc">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

and this is my JS:

```
$( '.mobile-navigation__navigation-list li a' ).on("click", function(){
  $('closeMenu()').click();
});
```

What should i change? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the attribute `onclick` on the `li` element.

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="closeMenu()">Close menu</li>
</ul>

<script>
  function closeMenu() {
    //Close Menu
  }
</script>
```